# c++11 for each on 2D std::vector C not working?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, foreach

Initialize a 2D vector called matrix.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix(512,std::vector<int>(512));
```

Now I want to resize it:

This works:

```
    matrix.resize(50);
    for(int i = 0; i<matrix.size() ; i++)
        matrix[i].resize(50);
```

And this does not work:

```
    matrix.resize(50);
    for(auto ele : matrix)
        ele.resize(50);
```

I am using `for(auto ele : container)` in other places, I should have support for C++11, using Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 12.0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are making copies of the inner vectors in each loop iteration. You need to use a reference:

```
for(auto& ele : matrix)
        ele.resize(50);
```

Comment: Upticked. For the OP's benefit, *in general*, use `auto const&` for direct read-only access, `auto&` for writable access, and `auto` for a copy that you can munge without affecting your container content. Methinks you're probably about to be reviewing your code for places where you can significantly bump performance with the first of those.